# Setting waterline model attribute to default value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js, waterline

I have a model attribute in my Sails.js project that I want to set back to its default value. With default value I mean what I specified using `defaultsTo` in the model file.

I've tried something like:

```
model.update({id:exampleId}, {myAttribute: null})

model.update({id:exampleId}, {myAttribute: default})
```

How can I make a model attribute go back to its default value from a controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this value off the sails object.

```
MODEL.update(id,{myAttribute:sails.models.MODEL.myAttribute.defaultsTo})
```